# How to create a script which adds role="presentation"

Tags: javascript, attributes

I want to create script which adds to all images on my page `role="presentation"` dynamically, but I dont know what type of function use for this. The image are added dynamically so I cant just add manually. Below I am uploading my source code.

```
//.attachment-large(class that img has)
//.elementor-inner-section (class that the div with images has)

(()=>{ function AddRole() { 
    const imageHook = document.querySelectorAll(".attachment-large"); 
    const boxHook = document.querySelector(".elementor-inner-section"); 
    boxHook.forEach((box) => { 
        imageHook.setAttribute("style","role: presentation") }); 
} AddRole() })();
```

Comment: Post code, not images of code.

Comment: NO images, show us the code here and the code that is giving a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`role` is an attribute itself (as well as the `style`). So you need to run:

```
imageHook.setAttribute('role', 'presentation');
```

By the way, running it for `imageHook` must be enough, without a loop traversing the `boxHook` -- you seem to have no dependency for that.